# Script not getting executed eventhough path variable is set properly to node.exe

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

I installed node.js and trying to run a script. Problem is I am not able to run the script which are in other folder.

For Ex:

Path to node.exe is in path `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. I have updated the same in `PATH` variable.

I have the script to be executed in `D:\TestScript\Test.js`

Now when I execute js script from root folder path like `>node D:\TestScript\Test.js` I get the error `Cannot find module webdriverio`.

But if I copy the test script to root folder and now execute `>node Test.js` everthing works fine.

Any pointer would help

Added Script:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var webdrivercss = require('webdrivercss');
var client = webdriverio.remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
});
webdrivercss.init(client, {
    screenshotRoot: 'tests/visual/baseline',
    failedComparisonsRoot: 'tests/visual/failures',
});
client
    .init()
    .url('https://www.google.co.in')
    .webdrivercss('login form', [{
        name: 'title',
        elem: '.container h2'
    }, {
        name: 'form',
        elem: '.container form'
    }])
    .end();
```

When I run npm ls command from D drive I get the output as

> `-- (empty)

Comment: Can you show your script, please, so we can see if perhaps you're not requiring your modules correctly or something?

Comment: It is not like the script are not working. The above is not working when I have them in different directory other than root folder of node js

Comment: What's your package.json file look like, from the D location, run npm ls and tell us the output.